# Shortcuts, ALT-rightclick not working on 16.04, Gnome 3.18

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-classic

I think the following two issues are related:

1) ALT-rightclick, Super-rightclick etc. have no effect on the gnome panel.

2) I cannot set certain shortcuts using System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts. For example, the ALT key is recognized as "Level3 Shift", and cannot be combined with any other key for a shortcut. The Windows key is recognized as "Multi key" and again cannot be combined with other keys.

I'm using Gnome Classic on Ubuntu 16.04. Gnome Version 3.18

Comment: Please do not ask more than one question if they aren't closely linked.

Comment: I did so because I think they are caused by the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two versions of Gnome-Classic Which come from Gnome 3.18 in Ubuntu 16.04. One is using [**Metacity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacity) as the [window manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager) and another uses [**Compiz**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiz), which is the same composition manager used by Unity.

I guess you're using the one which uses compiz, and this gnome-classic doesn't allow you to do **Alt-RightClick** in the panel so that you can customize it. But there is a workaround. You can quickly switch the window manager to `Metacity` and then make changes to the panel and then switch back to `compiz`.

To do so

- Open a terminal (`Alt-Ctrl-T`)
- Type `metacity --replace` and hit Enter
- Now do `Alt-RightClick` on the panel and customize what you want.
- Now press **Alt-F2** to bring the Run dialog
- Type `compiz --replace` there and hit Enter

**Keyboard Shortcut**

As for the keyboard shortcut, I guess you're using wrong Keyboard Layout. Change the layout to En-US by going to **Settings** -> **Text Entry** -> **Input Sources** and Add the *English (US)* Layout

Comment: Thanks! Regarding the keyboard layout: my keyboard is indeed a UK English keyboard, and the layout is correctly shown in the Settings. The same keyboard worked fine with Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Glad to help. But the SE way of saying thanks (if the answer is helpful) is voting up the answer :) And accepting it if that solves the problem. I think your second problem is unrelated with this one and hence should be asked in another question separately

Answer (score 0):

The above tip didn't work for me.  I tried the metacity --replace and that process hung.  And everything except the mouse stopped working: even my current terminal window no longer took text input.  Couldn't change window focus.  (I  had logged in with Gnome classic.)  After I logged out and logged back in again, I did a ps ax | grep first for metacity and then for compiz. Neither was running.
Alt -right mouse click does nothing for me.  Ubuntu 16.04.
I had been use flashback, but a recent system update screwed that so that watching a video switched primary/secondary monitors and changed monitor until I ran Settings - which switched them back on startup, but left all firefox tabs un-refreshable except by changing windows.  At least GDM basically works.